# jq: how to get 2 1d arrays side by side as output

Tags: json, jq, transpose

Say we have the following object in a json file:

> {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}

How can I get the following output?:

```
 "a"  "b"
  1    4
  2    5
  3    6
```

I've only managed to get them one after another but not side by side:

```
>jq -nc '{a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6]}'|jq '"a",.a[],"b", .b[]'
 "a"
  1
  2
  3
 "b"
  4
  5
  6
```

thanks.

Comment: this is great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generic solution (notice there is no mention of "a" or "b") using `transpose`:

```
(keys_unsorted | map(tojson)),   # the header line
 ([.[]] | transpose[])
| @tsv
```

#### Invocation

jq -r -f program.jq data.json

#### Output

```
"a" "b"
1   4
2   5
3   6
```